# Java reflection to compare 2 objects for each variable class

Tags: java, reflection, compare

I have a class that has some member variables one or more being another class also with member variables.

I can get the variables by calling: getDeclaredFields(); And the values of the Foo Object by calling field.get(obj) then iterating of them again to get the sub class variables.

My actual goal is to compare 2 Foo objects to know if there have the same values or not. My actual problem is to access to variable of the 2nd object

Thanks in advance

*First Object:*

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(){}
    private Integer someInt = 123;
    private Long someLong = 987654321L;
    private String someString = "qwertyuiop";
    private Bar bar = new Bar();
}
```

*Second Object:*

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(){}
    private Double someDouble = 123.456;
    private String innerString = "another String";
}
```

*main method and getting variables and values:*

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Foo foo2 = new Foo();
        getMemberFields(foo, foo2);
    }

    private static boolean getMemberFields(Object obj1, Object obj2) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {

        Class<?> objClass1 = obj1.getClass();
        Class<?> objClass2 = obj2.getClass();

        Field[] fields1 = objClass1.getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] fields2 = objClass2.getDeclaredFields();

        int id = 0;

        for(Field field1 : fields1)
        {
            field1.setAccessible(true);
            fields2[id].setAccessible(true);

            if (!field1.getType().isPrimitive() && !field1.getType().getName().contains("java.lang")) // if not int String char Long short...
            {
                getMemberFields(field1.get(obj1), fields2[id].get(obj2));
            } else {
                System.out.println("id : " + id);
                System.out.println("Field: " + field1.getName() + " value: " + field1.get(obj1));
                System.out.println("Field: " + fields2[id].getName()+ " value: " + fields2[id].get(obj2));

                if (field1.get(obj1) != fields2[id].get(obj2)) return false; // if different return false
            }
            id+=1;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Actually i have this bad result :

```
id : 0 Field: someInt value: 123 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class xxx.open.api.test.myTest.MyTest cannot access a member of class xxx.open.api.test.myTest.Foo with modifiers "private"
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkAccess(Field.java:1075)   
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:416)    
at xxx.open.api.test.myTest.MyTest.getMemberFields(MyTest.java:31)
at xxx.open.api.test.myTest.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:9)
```

Comment: Aside from the "this bad result", you are ignoring the result of invoking `getMemberFields` recursively inside the loop.

Comment: Doesn’t look like you set `fields2` accessible.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how is this possible ? i dont undertand why i have access to fields1[0].get(obj1) and not fields2[0].get(obj2)

Comment: @AndyTurner yes you right, i will fix that

Comment: Why not override the equals method so you can compare each field directly without using reflection

Comment: @jahe i wanted to directly have 1 unique method on my generic class (for my unit test), but well that's probably what I'm going to do

Comment: you can try insert `fields2[id].setAccessible(true);` at the beginning of the loop @Ruskof

Comment: `getDeclaredFields` is not enough as it only takes fields of the given class so you need to traverse the class chain. Also you have to filter out `static` and maybe `transient` fields. Additionally, it's not really fine to say "same" for equality: _same_ may be used to denote references that refer the same object, not checking their equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce your result with the [current version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70651309/3). Since you edited the code in a way that the problem disappeared, I have to emphasize that this is *not* the way, Stackoverflow works. Your question about a specific problem is supposed to contain the code necessary to reproduce the problem. The [*Answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70651309/2711488#answers) section is dedicated to contain solutions.

Besides the original problem of not calling `setAccessible` on the second `Field` instance, it’s not clear why you are using a second `Field` object in the first place.

There are two possible scenarios.

1. You assume both objects to have the same type. Then, there is no reason to operate with two arrays of `Field` objects. You can just use one array to access both objects.
2. You assume that the objects may have different types. Then it is entirely unreasonable to assume that the two arrays of `Field` objects of different classes correspond in any way.

In fact, [the documentation of `getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) specifies

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

and does not even state that calling `getDeclaredFields()` twice on the same `Class` object will return fields in the same order.

You should use your approach only for objects of the same type and just use one array of fields. When descending to objects contained in fields, use `equals` where appropriate, as certain types (e.g. collections) have equality rules for objects of different implementation classes.

For example

```java
static boolean equalByMemberFields(Object obj1, Object obj2)
                                                throws ReflectiveOperationException {

    if(obj1 == obj2) return true;
    else if(obj1 == null || obj2 == null) return false;

    Class<?> objClass1 = obj1.getClass();
    if(obj2.getClass() != objClass1) return false;

    Field[] fields = objClass1.getDeclaredFields();
    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true); // on all at once

    for(Field field : fields) {
        Object value1 = field.get(obj1), value2 = field.get(obj2);
        if(shouldDescend(field.getType())) {
            if( ! equalByMemberFields(value1, value2)) return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Field: " + field.getName()
                + ", value1: " + value1 + ", value2: " + value2);

            if(!Objects.equals(value1, value2)) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean shouldDescend(Class<?> type) throws NoSuchMethodException {

    if(type.isPrimitive() || type.isEnum()) return false;

    if(type.getClassLoader() == null) return false; // don't peek into core classes

    if(type.getMethod("equals", Object.class).getDeclaringClass() != Object.class)
        return false; // has overridden equals method

    return true;
}
```